# I can't check malware in google webmaster tools

Tags: malware, google-search-console, malware-detection

I'm trying to ask for a malware review for a website I made, but google webmaster tools has the following message :

Security Issues
We haven't detected any security issues on your site. If you need more information on security issues related to your site, please review our resources for hacked sites.

Although my website says that I have malicious code.

Does anyone know the procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a fetch under webmaster tools to get your site re-indexed and checked once more for malware.

A couple of weeks ago we had Google Shopping reporting malware but webmaster tools reporting that everything was okay. Strange.

So we used this website: http://sucuri.net/ to identify the problem and now we have no issues. It's free to scan but they charge for a fix, however they provide enough information under the free scan to allow an eagle-eyed developer to pinpoint and neutralise the malware.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What's your website name, and does it say "This site may harm your computer" in google search, or "This site may be hacked"? The security issues in webmaster tools is accompanied by these two warnings in google search. Otherwise Google probably does not know yet that you have malicious code.